# How do I shuffle the middle letters of every word in a string?

Tags: ruby, string

Trying to recreate the "Only smart people can read this" meme. Here's a sample:

> Hrad to blveiee taht you cluod aulaclty uesdnatnrd waht yor’ue
>   rdanieg. The phaonmneal pweor of the hmuan bairn, aoccdrnig to a
>   rscheearch at Cmabrigde Uinervtisy, sowhs taht it deosn’t mttaer in
>   waht oredr the ltteers in a wrod are, the olny iprmoatnt tihng is taht
>   the frist and lsat ltteer be in the rghit pclae.
>
> The rset can be a taotl mses and you can sitll raed it wouthit a
>   porbelm.
>
> Tihs is bcuseae the huamn biarn deos not raed ervey lteter by istlef,
>   but the wrod as a wlohe ptatren. Amzanig huh? Yaeh, and you awlyas
>   tghuhot slpeling was ipmorantt!

How do I create a Ruby method that jumbles the middle words for every word greater than 3 letters, in a sentence I pass it.

**Clarification:** I've posted this question and answer both at the same time. There's no code in the question because I posted it in the answer.

Comment: All the answer suggest that apostrophes can move but your text suggests this might not be correct in the word `yor’ue`. Obviously this assumption too could be incorrect as it is the only example and there is a possibility that the apostrophe would happen to land in the same location.

Comment: @engineersmnky There's also the fact that the sample text can randomize a whole paragraph, while the answers only randomize single strings with no periods. I'm just not reading into it too deeply.

Comment: @amingilani My answer works fine with paragraphs (or any amount of whitespace) and basic punctuation—although all of the answers so far, including mine, count apostrophes as "letters" and shuffle them, too.

Comment: @sagar made the observation (in comments on answers) that since no jumbled words (of 4 or more characters) above were the same as the original words, it could be assumed that that is a property demanded of every jumbled word. Is that reasonable? Let's first consider the words above having 4 letters (the middle two being distinct), of which there are 17. There are only two ways to sequence the middle two letters of those words, so the probability that all 17 are different than the original word is `0.5 ** 17 #=> 7.629e-06.` (cont.)

Comment: For the 17 words of length 5, this probability is somewhat less (because of the possibility of repeated characters) than `(5.0/6)**17 # => 0.045`. The product of these two probabilities is `7.629e-06 * 0.045 #=> 3.433e-07`. (Etcetera.) I think we may conclude that Sagar's inference was correct, meaning that the statement of the question is incomplete (and your answer is incorrect).

Comment: Note that you can pass an instance of [`Random`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Random.html) to `shuffle` in order to have deterministic output (based on an initial seed).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, I'll bite:

```
def srlabmce(str)
  str.gsub(/([\p{L}'])([\p{L}']{2,})([\p{L}'])/) { "#$1#{$2.chars.shuffle.join}#$3" }
end

puts srlabmce("Hard to believe that you could actually understand what you're reading")
# => Hrad to beviele taht you cuold atlculay unantdresd what yoru'e raeindg
```

See it on repl.it: https://repl.it/@jrunning/TrainedDangerousSlope

#### Update

I originally used the Regexp `/(\S)(\S+)(\S)/`, which counted as a "word" any sequence of three or more non-whitespace characters. This unfortunately counted punctuation as word characters, so e.g. "`Hello, world.`" might become "`Hlloe, wlodr.`"—the `,` and `.` were counted as the last "letters" of the words, and the actual last letters were moved.

I've updated it to use the Regexp `/([\p{L}'])([\p{L}']{2,})([\p{L}'])/`. The character class `\p{L}` corresponds to the Unicode category "Letters," so it works with basic diacritics, and I threw in `'` to match amingilani's implementation.

```
puts srlabmce("Quem ïd feugiat iaculisé éu mié tùrpus ïn interdùm grâvida, malesuada vivamus nam nullä urna justo conubia torétoré lorem.")
# => Qeum ïd fgieuat iliacusé éu mié tpùurs ïn iedùtnrm girâdva, madueasla vimavus nam nullä unra jutso cnboiua ttoréroé lerom.
```

#### Update 2

If we want to add the requirement that no word's letter order may be the same in the output as the input, we can modify the proc passed to `gsub` to call itself again until the order has changed:

```
def srlabmce(str)
  replacer = ->*{
    if $2.chars.uniq.size < 2 then $&
    else
      o = $2.chars.shuffle.join
      o == $2 ? replacer[] : "#$1#{o}#$3"
    end
  }
  str.gsub(/([\p{L}'])([\p{L}']{2,})([\p{L}'])/, &replacer)
end
```

We can still make this a one-liner, but its readability quickly deteriorates:

```
def srlabmce(str)
  str.gsub(/([\p{L}'])([\p{L}']{2,})([\p{L}'])/, &(r = ->*{ $2.chars.uniq.size < 2 ? $& : (o = $2.chars.shuffle.join) == $& ? r[] : "#$1#{o}#$3" }))
end
```

See it on repl.it: https://repl.it/@jrunning/TrainedDangerousSlope-2

Comment: You win this round Jordan :) What's the motivation behind the method name?

Comment: @amingilani really? Maybe Cambridge should have mentioned that the context is important to reading a word that is `srlabmce`[d]?

Comment: This doesn't guarantee each word is jumbled though. A shuffle can retain the original order.

Comment: @SagarPandya Is that a requirement specified somewhere? OP's implementation has the same behavior.

Comment: I'm going by the sample text (no words of length 4 or more are in 'correct' order) and the point of the experiment.

Comment: It's taken me way longer than I care to admit to figure out 'scramble'

Comment: @JordanRunning he caught me off-guard and I think he's right. I won't change the accepted answer though, but heh, my code only needed minor changes to be right :P

Comment: I've updated my answer, but it's not nearly as neat now. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: `srlabmce "feet" #=> SystemStackError: stack level too deep`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland That is a beautiful edge case.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Fixed. It ain't getting any prettier.

Answer (score 6):

**Edit:** this code now guarantees words can't accidentally be scrambled to their original text. E.g. `read` will now always be scrambled to `raed`.

**Edit 2:** if words can't be scrambled, it'll return the original word, e.g. `jumble 'feet' # => 'feet'`

Create a method to `jumble` individual words, and call it via `mess_up` for each word in the sentence

```
def mess_up(sentence)
  sentence = sentence.downcase.split(' ').map { |e| jumble(e) }.join(' ')
  sentence[0] = sentence[0].upcase
  sentence
end

def jumble(word)
  return word if word.size <= 3
  str = word.split('')
  f = str.shift
  l = str.pop
  return word if str.uniq.size == 1
  str = [f, str.shuffle, l].join('')
  return jumble(str) if word == str
  str
end

mess_up "Hard to believe that you could actually understand what you're reading"
# => "Hrad to bleevie taht you cuold aactlluy unrdnestad waht y'ruoe rendaig"
```

**Motivation**

I did this as a fun experiment when I saw the post. Was going to push it in a Gist, but realized someone may search for this at some point and SO is the best place for it.

Comment: Look at your output, some of your words are not jumbled in the middle so this answer is wrong.

Comment: @SagarPandya, for a four word, there are two letter in the middle to scramble, which means they have 2 possible scrambled states, of which 1 is different from the original. Meaning, there's a 50% chance of the scrambled four-letter world being the same as the original. This doesn't make the answer wrong, since if you run the same command again, it'll return a different output. I just reran the command and I got `"Hrad to beivlee taht you cluod allctuay usdnnreatd waht yro'ue reading"`

Comment: Look at the sample text in your question, all four-letter (or longer) words are jumbled in the middle. Do you not want to create a string matching this criteria?

Comment: @SagarPandya fine! Here you go, better? Thanks for forcing me to improve the code, though :)

Comment: Yes, this is now correct. Though the handling of apostrophes may be seen as an issue, nonetheless upvoted now.

Comment: ` jumble "feet" #=> SystemStackError: stack level too deep`.

Comment: Does a four letter word with identical middle letters get jumbled? (There doesn't seem to be such a word in the example passage.) If not, this can be fixed with a guard clause before `str` is reassigned: `return word if str.uniq.count == 1` so that the word is returned unchanged.

Answer (score 4):

```
def scramble(sentence)
  sentence.split.map do |word|
    word.size <= 3 || word[1..-2].squeeze.size == 1 ? word : word[0] +
      word[1..-2].chars.shuffle.join('') + word[-1]
  end.join(' ')
end

scramble "Little Miss Muffat sat on a tuffet"
  #=> "Llitte Miss Mfauft sat on a tffuet"
```

If a shuffled word (of length 4 or more) must differ from the original word, one could write the following. Note one cannot shuffle a word of length 4 or greater to be different than the original word if all characters other than the first and last are the same.

```
def scramble(sentence)
  sentence.split.map do |word|
    word.size <= 3  || word[1..-2].squeeze(word[0]).size == 1 ? word : 
      word[0] + my_shuffle(word[1..-2]) + word[-1]
  end.join(' ')
end

def my_shuffle(str)
  a = arr = str.chars
  loop do
    a = a.shuffle
    break a unless a == arr
  end.join('')
end
```

Comment: Look at the sample text. All words of length 4 or more are jumbled in the middle. Downvote was mine. This code can (by fluke) produce words in their original order (of lettering).

Comment: @Sagar, I didn't notice that requirement until after I posted my answer, then by reading the OPs answer. I therefore edited my answer to conform. I see Jordan had the same misunderstanding. Note the scrambled word "what" in the asker's answer.